# Return new object with another list of objects

Tags: c#

**Model1 -**

```
    public class model1
    {
       public long Id { get; set; }
       public Guid Unique { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

**Model2 -**

```
public class model2
{
   public long model2Id { get; set; }
   public List<model1> Model1Items { get; set; } = new List<model1>();
}
```

If I wanted to `return new` of `model2`, how would I do that?

```
return new 
{
   model2Id = 3423432,
   Model1Items = [
      {
        Id = 212,
        Unique = 23432
      }
   ]
}
```

I get an error - `Invalid expression [` after `Model1Items`

Comment: Reading a book or documentation about basic c# syntax would be more useful than asking it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer looks very JavaScript-y, but you have it tagged "C#".  It's   This is how you'd do it:

```
return new model2
{
    model2Id = 3423432,
    Model1Items = new List<model1>
    {
        new model1
        {
            Id = 212L,
            Unique = Guid.NewGuid()
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is not as concise as javascript. So, given your code this is how you would do it:

```
var m2 = new model2()
{
    model2Id = 3423432,
    Model1Items = new List<model1>()
    {
        new model1() {Id = 212, Unique = new Guid("23432") },
        new model1() {Id = 121, Unique = new Guid("43234") }
        // etc...
    }
};
```

For documentation on initializers, see the docs at microsoft here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return new model2
{
   Id = 3423432,
   Model1Items = new List<model1>(){
     new model1() 
      {
        Id = 212,
        Unique = 23432
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Copied from the initial post (before the Josh changed it)